# PHP File Download Using Hidden IFrame Without Saving

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, download

I apologize in advance for the confusing question wording, but I couldn't figure out how to put this.

I essentially have a string in a database that I intend to make available for user download. How would I go about doing this?

I was attempting to use ajax, but I wasn't sure how to go about it.

The following jquery code is executed when the download link is pressed

```
$.ajax({

    url: 'index.php/script/downloadFile',
    type: 'post',
    data: {name: $(this).text()}

});
```

The relevant PHP code looks like:

```
public function downloadScript(){

    $name = $_POST['name'];

    $filename = $name . ".txt";
    $string = //String that comes from database using name to create query
    $filename = $name . ".txt";

    header('Content-type: text/plain');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"');
    header("Content-Length: " . strlen($string));
    header("Connection: close");

    echo $string;
}
```

Essentially, I want the string to be there for a user to download as a text file. I didn't know if AJAX was the right way to do this or if there was a better way to do the same task. (I was assuming the better way would be to incorporate a hidden iframe somehow)

For a little more information, I have a list of elements:

John

Jeff

Joe

Jack

When one is clicked, I want to send the text of that element's name to the php file to form the query.

That's why I don't have a simple href setup to start the file download.

**EDIT:**

While I'm at it, is there anyway for me to get more than one of these files, say there are multiple strings that are returned from the database, save them as separate text files, zip them up, and send them to the user? Or, would that require saving to the server?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Make sure you sanitize your input here.  There are hundreds of ways this can be exploited. $name = "`cat /etc/passwd`";

Comment: Haha, well the list names come straight from a database, so i dont know how the name could be something harmful

Comment: If you're reading the variable from $_POST, then it can be manipulated by some unscrupulous hacker.  Better safe than sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just make it a link

```
<ul>
    <li class="click_link">John</li>
    <li class="click_link">Bob</li>
</ul>

<script>
$('li').click(function(e) {
    window.location.href = 'getfile.php?name=' + $(this).text();
});
</script>
```

Then change your `$_POST` to a `$_GET`.

This will download the file as long as your headers are set correctly.

Comment: Hmm, the only issue is, the exact element is determined via jquery. Would I be able to add the href to the element after? Essentially, the download is a custom right click option on the page.

Comment: Can you give me a little more info?  So you have a DIV that is clicked and that pushes the $.ajax?

Comment: You could just set the title attribute on the anchor tag to be the file name and use jQuery to fetch the title value and send the ajax call that way. Just make sure to use proper headers for file download in the return.

Comment: Yeah, essentially, there's a list of elements. Right Clicking provides a menu that pushes the ajax request, and the text of that list element is the name sent to the php file. Sorry, should I include that in the question?

Comment: Thanks! Haha, that worked perfectly, didn't even need the AJAX.