# sending data to php and download file

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, download

I need to send data to php file and download it.

My script is working correctly when I call it directly, but when I send data with AJAX it doesn't download at all.

My question would be: How to send data to php file and download file automatically but of course stay on the same page?

Part of the code that is working when called directly...

**PHP file**

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer'); 
header("Content-type: application/ms-word");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=ponuda.doc");

$productsArr = json_decode($_POST['object']);
$html = "<tr>";
foreach($productsArr as $product)
{
    //something
}
....
echo $html;
```

**AJAX call:**

```
$.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "test_download.php",
          data: { object:productsJSON },
          cache: false
        });
```

Comment: You must redirect to the download page, if the headers are set correctly and the browser recognizes it's downloading a file instead of displaying a page, then this will work. It's like clicking on a .exe link, your browser won't white page - it simply stats the download. Ajax will not work for making a file download, ever, it's impossible.

Comment: you can go through this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11477052/php-file-download-using-hidden-iframe-without-saving?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I do the following:

1. Include the [exchanger.js](http://pastebin.com/vV5bnTYn) javascript file in your head section
2. Initialize the exchanger object on page load: `theBuffer = new exchanger('dwnld');`
3. Create a javascript function that you will call whenever you want to initiate a file download
   :

   ```
    function downloadFile(){
         // you can add parameters to the function as needed to pass in dynamic data sent to the back end download handler
         data = "http://your_backend_file_download_handler.php?param1=val1&param2=val2&etc=whatever";  // send whatever data you need to the php program via query string parameters
         theBuffer.sendData(data);  // initiate the file download
    }
   ```

   Note: The php back end file download program that handles the requests can do whatever it needs to do with the parameters you send it in order to put together/retrieve the correct data/file for download.  After much tinkering [this combination](http://pastebin.com/EPkMv2qM) is what consistently works for me
4. Include this little bit of html in your body section.  I usually put it just before the closing body tag:

   ```
    <iframe name="dwnld" id="dwnld" style="width:0;height:0;border:0">
    </iframe>

    Note:  the id value assigned to the iframe is the same value given in step 2 when initializing.
   ```

**The result** is that the user never leaves the current page to download any number of files because the actual download is handled in a separate page (aka the iframe).  I have used it without issue in all of my projects for years now.

Answer (score 0):

I think You can't send header to browser by ajax, but You can use this, great thing.

http://johnculviner.com/jquery-file-download-plugin-for-ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads/

```
$.fileDownload('file.mp3')
    .done(function () { alert('File download a success!'); })
    .fail(function () { alert('File download failed!'); });
```